# cron jobs - difference between editing "/etc/crontab" and "crontab -e"

Tags: shutdown, cron

Trying to set up a daily `cron` job to shut down a server.

One source suggests editing `/etc/crontab`

Another suggests `crontab -e` (with `sudo`)

I tried the latter, and my process did not run (if I recall, it was `30 23 * * * shutdown -h`)

I also note that in the nano editor, it was working on a `.tmp` file? (top of nano says: `/tmp/crontab.9zeTNt/crontab` )

What is going on? How can I fix this?

Comment: If you add your shutdown command to the `/etc/crontab` file,  your line should look like `30 23 * * * root shutdown -h now`.  You need to specify which user is going to run the command.

Comment: looking back - i added that exact command to "crontab -e", actually.

Comment: `sudo crontab -e` does not edit the `/etc/crontab` file.  You have to manually edit that file.

Comment: i guess i'm still unclear then as to the difference between the two then?

Comment: thanks. edited the /etc/crontab. hopefully it works tonight.

Answer (score 3):

**`crontab -e`:**

Usable on a per user basis; opens the `cron` table for the invoking user for editing (a temporary file in `/tmp/` e.g. `/tmp/crontab.<RANDOM>/crontab`, as you have seen) and upon saving the content, sanity checkings are done. If passed, the file is moved into `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` i.e. the `cron` spool directory and saved with the filename being same as the invoking user's name. As the `cron` table is being saved for the invoking username (e.g. `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/foobar`, assuming username `foobar`); as all `cron` jobs are run as that user so no username field is needed, each entry here needs 6 fields (you know these already i presume)

**`/etc/crontab`:**

This is the system `cron` table (`crontab` file), there is no notion of invoking user here as only superuser can edit this file, do this file needs 7 fields, with an additional username field at space/tab separated 6th field. This is true for all `cron` files in `/etc/cron.d/` too. Another difference with `crontab -e` is that you need to open the file as an argument to an editor or any program/shell that can do I/O whereas with `crontab -e` the file would be open with the editor mentioned as `VISUAL` or `EDITOR` or `/usr/bin/editor` -- the first one wins.

---

**Why your command failed inside `cron`:**

Because `shutdown` can only be run as superuser or capable users, and the invoking user presumably does not fall into that category. You can put the in `root`'s `crontab` by `sudo crontab -e` or put it `/etc/crontab`, i usually always prefer individual user tables.

**Notes:**

Also `cron` uses a minimal `PATH` by default, and also `SHELL` is set as `sh` (`dash` in Ubuntu); these two are common `cron` pitfalls.

While debugging, always check `syslog`, and redirect relevant command's STDOUT and STDERR to a file for analyzing later.

Answer (score 1):

When you edit `/etc/crontab` you are editing a global crontab

When you edit via `crontab -e`, you are editing your local, personal one. The editor is launched on a temp file so that the file can be checked before it is written to its real location.

When you edited, and saved, and exited the editor (you must quit the process for the filecheck and copy-over to occur) you need to confirm you got a message by which "new crontab was installed"

Comment: thanks, i think i understand. so i should just edit /etc/crontab then?

Comment: Either will do. When testing and to check things are working try `* * * * * date > /home/yourname/crontest`

Comment: "When you edited, and saved, and exited the editor (you must quit the process for the filecheck and copy-over to occur) you need to confirm you got a message by which "new crontab was installed"" can you elaborate on that? i wasn't getting that message and that may be where the problem is?