# Crontab never works on ubuntu server

Tags: command-line, server, bash, scripts, cron

I'm really new to ubuntu server, and i've been having a lot of issues with crontab across this week and i can't really figure out what's wrong with it, i tried everything i saw here to no avail.

So, i have a script that in theory should shut off the server after a few minutes of net inactivity. The script executes without any problem, and works perfectly if done so manually.
The issue i've been facing happens when I try to setup cron to execute this script.

Here's the code

```
#!/bin/bash 
set -o nounset -o errexit -o pipefail

MARKER_FILE="/tmp/ssh-inactivity-flag"

STATUS=$(netstat | grep ssh | grep ESTABLISHED &>/dev/null && echo active || echo inactive)   

if [ "$STATUS" == "inactive" ]; then
  if [ -f "$MARKER_FILE" ]; then
    echo "Powering off due to ssh inactivity."
    rm --force "$MARKER_FILE"
    /sbin/poweroff  # See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/56711
  else
    # Create a marker file so that it will shut down if still inactive on the next time this script runs.
    echo "El cabron aun no se ha ido :("
    touch "$MARKER_FILE"
  fi
else
  # Delete marker file if it exists
  rm --force "$MARKER_FILE"
  echo "No se va el pussi"
fi
```

Here's the crontab setting:

```
*/1 *   * * *   root    /home/angel/idle.sh
```

And here's what it returns on /var/log/syslog

```
Jun 29 13:37:01 torreon CRON[1951]: (angel) CMD (root    /home/angel/idle.sh)
```

In theory cron is executing the script, but it doesn't seem to work or return anything. I'm really lost and i don't know what i could have done wrong, so if anyone can please guide me it would be greatly appreciated.

(Also i've tried with other scripts that are just like one line of code and those didn't work neither.)

Comment: `CMD (root    /home/angel/idle.sh)` shows that cron recognizes `root` as a part of the  command ... Specifying a user is not supported here in a user crontab, so remove the user part i.e. `root` ... If you need to execute your script with elevated privileges, then add it with `sudo crontab -e`

Comment: Crap, removing that and executing crontab with sudo seemed to fix it. Sorry for asking such dumb question, thx you so much.

Comment: Don't be sorry ... That is a valid and smart question because it saved your time and will save a lot of other users time when they search for the same issue and find this post ... You are welcome.

Comment: Somewhat related: [cron jobs - difference between editing "/etc/crontab" and "crontab -e"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900876/cron-jobs-difference-between-editing-etc-crontab-and-crontab-e)

Answer (score 7):

`CMD (root    /home/angel/idle.sh)` shows that CRON recognizes `root` as a part of the command and tries to execute it which, normally, will fail ... Specifying a user is not supported here in a user `crontab`, so remove the user part i.e. `root`.

The command `crontab -e`(*without `sudo`*) edits the invoking user's `crontab`.

If you need to execute your script with elevated privileges, then add it with `sudo crontab -e` which will edit the `root`’s user `crontab`.

From [`man crontab`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/crontab.5.html):

> Each user has their own crontab, and commands in any given crontab
> will be executed as the user who owns the crontab.

and:

> The following lists the content of a regular system-wide `crontab`
> file.  **Unlike**  a  user's `crontab`, this file has the **username** field, as
> used by `/etc/crontab`.