# Crontab -l not reporting any jobs after /etc/crontab edit

Tags: python, cron

I want to run a Python script at certain intervals.
So I edited the /etc/crontab file and added this:

```
*/2 9-10 * * 1,2,4,5 administrator DISPLAY=:0 python3 /home/administrator/main.py
```

So I want to run this script as the user administrator.

- When I execute `sudo crontab -l` reports 'No crontab for root'

So, I don't think the crontabs are registered at all. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cron jobs - difference between editing "/etc/crontab" and "crontab -e"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900876/cron-jobs-difference-between-editing-etc-crontab-and-crontab-e)

Comment: `crontab -l` is for the user's own crontab, not for any jobs that might be set to run as that user in the system crontab (which is what `/etc/crontab` is. To add files to the user's crontab, you should use the `crontab` command itself (e.g., via `crontab -e`, `crontab /path/to/file`, etc.)

Comment: @muru I get the difference between a local and root crontab (I noticed that when crontab -l reported no jobs for administrator. But why does sudo crontab -l doesn't report the cronjobs for root from the /etc/crontab file? I have edited the main question to clarify this is not a root vs local crontab problem.

Comment: @Mathias they are saved in separate locations, `sudo crontab -l` reads `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`

Comment: @steeldriver oh ok, so it _is_ a local vs system crontab issue, instead of a local vs root issue. I fully understand now. Thanks a lot. If you post your comment as answer I can accept it.